# Auth0 and HostedPages

Tags: auth0

I am having an issue with Auth0 and the callback.  If I enable 'Customize Login Page' for Auth0's hosted page I get a callback url that looks something like this:

http://localhost:3000/callback?code=xxxxx&state=xxxx.xxxx

But if I disable the 'Customize Login Page,' I get a callback url that looks something like this:

http://localhost:3000/callback#access_token=xxxxx&expires_in=xxxx&token_type=Bearer&state=xxxxxx&id_token=xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I couldn't find anything in documentation for this behavior.  I would prefer it to behave it as the latter.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  When the Login Page is customized, the, responseType is set to 'code' by default.  It needs to be set to

```
    responseType: 'token id_token'
```

I was testing with a Google account.  I'm not sure whether it behaves differently with other account types.

Comment: Using `token id_token` means that you are implementing `implicit` OAuth. Is this your intention? Implicit OAuth runs in the browser without involving a website. Normally you want to use `authorization code grant` which uses a Client ID and Client Secret where the web server receives the tokens and is considered more secure (3-legged OAuth).

Comment: @JohnHanley, this was a configuration on the Auth0's side.